# Smack 4.2 OutgoingChatMessageListener not getting callback (Android)

Tags: android, openfire, smack

I am using Andorid smack 4.2 version the lastest one as of now, 
I have implemented `IncomingChatMessageListener` and `OutgoingChatMessageListener`.

> IncomingChatMessageListener listener is working properly and getting
>   the callbacks, but the OutgoingChatMessageListener is not getting any
>   call. I wonder why
>
> Can anyone point the mistake or what am I missing in the code.

Below is how I have Implemented :

```
private IncomingChatMessageListener incomingChatMessageListener;
private OutgoingChatMessageListener outgoingChatMessageListener;


 /**
 * get ChatManager Instance
 *
 * @return
 */
private ChatManager getChatManagerInstance() {
    if (chatManager == null && getConnection() != null) {
        chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(getConnection());
    }
    return chatManager;
}



// Add Listeners
   getChatManagerInstance().addIncomingListener(incomingChatMessageListener);


   getChatManagerInstance().addOutgoingListener(outgoingChatMessageListener);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve it ?

Comment: Nope I didn't find one

Comment: eventually we dropped the idea of using this